# Блок на всю высоту экрана без использования vh

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я бы хотел, чтобы `.div3` был на 100% высоты экрана, но без использования vh, это можно сделать? Чтобы контент не обрезался, также
Без js

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.div1 {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div2 {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div3 {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #3656f7;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">

  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      123
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто пробросьте высоту до нужного блока. Нужно от чего-то отталкиваться, а у Вас только `<html>` имеет внятные размеры. `min-height` - это "ограничитель", но не задание размера.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div3 {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 30px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">

  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      123
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Просто проблема в том, что `height: 100%` у меня бывало дело урезала контент

Comment: @МихаилКамахин: потому и урезает - у html есть размер, затем у div1 размера нет (только ограничение) и всё... пошло-поехало, ведь процентные размеры они от размеров родителя вычисляются.  Эх, не помню где статья про min-max/height-width...

Comment: Ну тогда придётся использовать vh, всё-таки. vh просто некорректно на некоторых браузерах высчитывается

Comment: @МихаилКамахин: просто div3 {overflow: hidden;} придётся добавлять. И самое главное - не работайте Вы с пустышками, наполните "рыбой" блоки - их ничто не растягивает. Это как сдутый воздушный шарик пинать, поверьте.

Answer (score 1):

Это будет работать вот так, без обрезания контена в `.div3`:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.div1 {
  height: 100%;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100%;
}

.div3 {
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #3656f7;
  color: white;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">

  <div class="div2">
    <div class="div3">
      123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123 123
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```